# Missing icons in unordered list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this unordered list with fontawesome icon instead of the default list style. My problem is that in the second level the icon is only displayed for the first list item.
I am using the pseudo before to display the icons and when I check it with inspector the pseudo before is there for each list item, but it is not displayed for all of them.

```css
.docs-sidebar {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        min-height: 500px;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul li::before {
        content: "\f105";
        color: #5f88c2;
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: -15px;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul li a {
        color: #727272;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul li a:hover {
        color: #5f88c2;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul li ul.dropdown-menu {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul li ul li {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul li ul.dropdown-menu li::before {
        content: "\f105";
        color: #5f88c2;
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 8px;
    }

    .docs-sidebar ul li ul li a {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="cl-content">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">

                <div class="docs-sidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                               <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">List item 4</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">List item 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-8">
                Some text ....
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized, this solves it:

```
.docs-sidebar ul li {
        position: relative;
    }
```